# Is there a way to make a class member object's template call a different constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the class Matrix there is a member variable that is of type `QArray<QArray<T>>`. I am able to call the outside class QArray one param constructor with a member initializer list but for the inside class I am not sure how to do it. The inside QArray will use the default constructor first and then I will have to use a loop to make each matrix[i] use the 1 param constructor. Here is the code:

```
#include "QArray.h"
class Matrix {
    QArray<QArray<T>> matrix;

    Matrix(int n) : matrix(n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            matrix[i] = QArray<T>(n);
        }
    }
}
```

As a work around I changed the type to `SA<SA<T> *>` and changed `matrix[i] = new SA<T>(cols)`. This will prevent the default constructor from being called but I would like to write the class the way above.

Comment: Why not just have a `QArray` who's size is `n*n`, rather than having this complex array-inside-array thing?

Comment: For this assignment I need to use my professors class QArray inside my matrix class.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it must be a `QArray` of `QArray`s. My point is that you could just have a `QArray<T>`, allocate `n*n` entries, and simply convert 2D matrix accesses into 1D linear accesses.

Comment: The guideline for this assignment wants us to implement it this way. The professor explicitly stated he wanted QArray<QArray<T>> but the TA said to do QArray<QArray<T>* > *. I don't see the reason for this if you can pick the one param constructor instead of default. I also want to apologize for not stating that from the start.

Comment: If `QArray` is anything like `std::vector`, it may have a two-parameter constructor taking a size and a value, so that `QArray<int>(10, 42)` creates an array of 10 elements, each set to 42. In this case, you could write `matrix(n, QArray<T>(n))`. If `QArray` doesn't have such a constructor, then I suspect the loop you have, or something substantially similar, is the best you can do.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using? There is no such thing as QArray in standard Qt4 or Qt5. Why is your instructor refusing to use an one dimensional structure of size `n*n`? Because it makes no sense to prevent a student from using the best alternative out there. Have a discussion with your professor.

Comment: Are you certain your instructor did not mean [`QVarLengthArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvarlengtharray.html`)?

Comment: QArray is a array class made by my professor and is not related to Qt. I don't know how this got tagged as Qt. @igor the 2 param constructor doesn't have that capability and I'm not allowed to change that class.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer : No**. 
You can't construct your `QArray` without using the constructors provided. In order to use a initialisation list there need to be a constructor which accept initialisation list. If we are talking about [this QArray](https://doc.qt.io/archives/2.3/qarray.html), then no, you can't.

Actually, why are you bothered about the default constructor be called? Qt is designed so that most objects can be default constructed then set. The default constructor is very lightweight.

*You should be worried about the fact you are using a class defunct since 2005. You should also be worried to not be allowed to use  `nxn` contiguous memory for your matrix.*

Comment: Just to clarify the QArray is a made up class and is not related to Qt.